# How to express data from different columns in a pivot table?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How should the pivot table code be edited so I can get the desired output below?

[Desired output 2 - multi-column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NlNn.png)

An example of the data source [Data Source Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZX0S.png)

I'm running into issues in the second half of the code -

//define data source column to be referenced for columns in pivot table

> in the code, i'm defining column 0 which is year
>   i need it to be a breakdown of year (column 0 in source) and (column 1 in source).

//define how values should be expressed in pivot table, as well as data source column where values should be taken from

> in the code below, I've only selected column 3
>   i need a sum of columns 3 and 4 for the values, expressed separately.

```
 function addPivotTable1(spreadsheetId1, pivotSourceDataSheetId1, destinationSheetId1)
 //workbook id, data source sheet id, destination sheet id
 {
   var requests = [{
     'updateCells': {
       'rows': {
         'values': [
           {
             'pivotTable': {
               'source': {
                 //define cells in data source sheet, starting with 0,0 for cell A1
                 'sheetId': pivotSourceDataSheetId1,
                 'startRowIndex': 0,
                 'startColumnIndex': 0,
                 'endRowIndex': 463,
                 'endColumnIndex': 4,
               },
               'rows': [
                 //define column in source sheet that will be in pivot table row
                 {
                   'sourceColumnOffset': 2,
                   'showTotals': true,
                   'sortOrder': 'ASCENDING',
                   'valueBucket': {
                     'buckets': [
                       {
                         'stringValue': 'Number of Accounts',
                       },
                     ],
                   },
                 },
                       //define last row in the source column for reference
                       {
                   'sourceColumnOffset': 463,
                   'showTotals': true,
                   'sortOrder': 'ASCENDING',
                   'valueBucket': {},
                 },
               ],

                 //define data source column to be referenced for columns in pivot table
               'columns': [
                 {
                   'sourceColumnOffset': 0,
                   'sortOrder': 'ASCENDING',
                   'showTotals': true,
                   'valueBucket': {},
                 },
               ],

                     //define how values should be expressed in pivot table, as well as data source column where values should be taken from
               'values': [
                 {
                   'summarizeFunction': 'SUM',
                   'sourceColumnOffset': 3,


                 },
               ],
               'valueLayout': 'HORIZONTAL',
             },
           },
         ],
       },
          //define cell in destination sheet where pivot table should be placed, 0,0 for top of sheet
       'start': {
         'sheetId': destinationSheetId1,
         'rowIndex': 0,
         'columnIndex': 0,
       },
       'fields': 'pivotTable',
     },
   }];

   var response =
       Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': requests}, spreadsheetId1);

 }
```

Comment: how should your pivot table of two columns look like? show an example.

Comment: hi Turo, I've edited the post to add an image capture of how the pivot table should look. Thanks!

Comment: As I understand a pivot-Table, the contents of the data in one column gets the header of a column in the output.table, so i don't see a pivot here.

Comment: Hi Turo, sorry to confuse you - I did manage to figure out the first part of my question actually, so I've edited to this question to reflect the part that i cannot solve. Thanks!

Comment: values is an array, have you tried `[  {  'summarizeFunction': 'SUM','sourceColumnOffset': 3},  {  'summarizeFunction': 'SUM','sourceColumnOffset': 4}]`

Comment: hmm doing that results in empty cells within the values section